# PubNub - Pushing HTML Updates

Tags: python, html, push-notification, pubnub

I am currently attempting to push html updates to a page for a user using [PubNub](https://pubnub-prod.appspot.com/). I want to push html code to the user (this includes links, quotes, making html necessary), and add it to the end of a table for the user.

I am currently attempting to use the api to send a message as follows:

```
info = pubnub.publish({
        'channel' : 'myChannel',
        'message' : {
        'some_text' : message
        }
    })
```

Where message is:

```
<div class="content">Message text here.<img src="image.gif" border="0" alt="" title="laugh out loud" class="inlineimg" /></div>
```

My issue is that I am receiving the following message when I attempt to send a page update:

```
</div> is not JSON serializable
```

I am assuming this is occurring because I am attempting to send html code?

Any recommendations on how to fix this / better ways to do this? This is my first attempt at "pushing" messages to a webpage, so I may be implementing this all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to send raw HTML via PubNub and running into the **"JSON not Serializable"** issue.  Firstly, you are correct in assuming that you **Can push HTML** code!  Hurray.  Just make sure that the data you place inside the `"message"` is in fact a **STRING**.  The following types are JSON Serializable:

1. Objects
2. Arrays
3. Strings
4. Numbers

Make sure to not send special python classes or functions.  These will not serialize.  String content can include any **UTF-8** character **single-byte** and **multi-byte**.

Use this Python for the `"message"`:

```
message = '''<div class="content">Message text here.<img src="image.gif" border="0" alt="" title="laugh out loud" class="inlineimg" /></div>'''
```

Comment: What's the best way to send the html code, since it contains links, images (just links to images, they are hosted elsewhere)?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am parsing a webpage using BeautifulSoup to extract the html content, and passing it to the pubnub.publish command. It looks like the content I was attempting to pass to pubnub.publish was still a BeautifulSoup object.

I converted it to a string, but now is failing to send the actual string. Is there a size limitation on the message or something that is causing this to silently fail?

Comment: 1.8KB is the limit.  Max Message size is 1.8KB and there are a few ways to get around this including: 1.) Sending Meta Data rather than the entire payload.  2.) upload the payload to S3, send link via PubNub.Publish() method.  3.) Split the message into 1K chunks, and reassemble on the client.

Comment: I don't think the messages I am trying are larger than 1.8KB. I might try saving the html to a local webserver, and then pushing the link out. Do you happen to have examples of updating a page using content from a specified html document like this? Or even just adding the message payload text to a page?

Comment: Great question!  You can see an example here using PubNub to push HTML content to a web page or mobile device like an iPhone with Webkit Safari or Desktop Chrome/Firefox/IE - https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/app-showcase/content-commander

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at in a bit, and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I am no web expert but to me sounds like you should define a model and send that instead.  You then would deserialize the model and update the client. That way you can use JSon and you won't run into any issues.

If you absolutely have to send the HTML, Another option when transferring HTML is to encode it in a base 64 string.  With this approach you would have encode the string prior to sending it and decoding it on the receiving client.  There is plenty of information on encoding base64 strings on google.  This keeps the string from tripping up on HTML tags and such.

Here is an example of what encoding to and from base64 looks like: http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html
For example the following code:

```
<img src="images/mypicture.jpg"></img>
<div id="chat-box"/>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Would look like this as a base64 string

```
PGltZyBzcmM9ImltYWdlcy9teXBpY3R1cmUuanBnIj48L2ltZz4KPGRpdiBpZD0iY2hhdC1ib3gi
```

Lz4KPHVsPgogIDxsaT5JdGVtIDE8L2xpPgogIDxsaT5JdGVtIDI8L2xpPgo8L3VsPg==